# Is Ubuntu at war with VLC?

Tags: support

Once again I come with yet another question. I don't know if I am the only one facing this problem because I have looked through the tags for same problems, hoping someone must have it already but I have seen none, so now I ask.
Is Ubuntu at some kind of war with VLC? If yes, let us know so as we know what to do. If not, then why is it that each time I tried to install vlc I get such errors? I will upload a screenshot. One funny thing is that at the software center it asks you to send an error report which I always do but nothing, in a form of solution has reached my machine yet.

Is it just me someone else is facing this same problem?

Thank you.[image: Installing VLC from the Ubuntu Software Center]

Answer (score 6):

No. Ubuntu is not at war with anyone.

Comment: My imagination is going wild here.