# Humor == or != Meta Post?

Tags: discussion

Do we need humor when we post here in Meta?  I am Newbie with a little concern here. Any answer will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: meta makes me laugh a lot, sometimes when the author intended, and sometimes not... but for sure there is no *requirement* for meta posts to be funny!

Comment: @Zanna you hit me in the my nose there my friend :)

Comment: I would be interested to know, what inspired this question?

Comment: A newbie like me don't know all the standard procedures when posting here, and most of the time, we're afraid to mingle with others because we have less knowledge with Ubuntu.  And I've read some posts that contains has humor and it attracts large number of views and answers.  That's it.  Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 20):

Humor? Or ***no*** humor?

Either way works for me.

---

In all seriousness, though, here are some hilarious meta posts:

- [Ubuntu misspellings](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15684/ubuntu-misspellings)
- [Are there any memes on Ask Ubuntu?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/11750/are-there-any-memes-on-ask-ubuntu)
- [Ten tips to handle your question in the worst possible way](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15344/ten-tips-to-handle-your-question-in-the-worst-possible-way)
- [Is Jorge Castro a Robot?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1900/is-jorge-castro-a-robot)
- [Can't edit due to mention of The Walking Dead](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7223/cant-edit-due-to-mention-of-the-walking-dead) (though the hilarity is unintentional)
- [Ask Ubuntu Chat Twitter Bot](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16210/ask-ubuntu-chat-twitter-bot) (though, admittedly, the capybara is doing most of the heavy lifting)

Hmm, I thought that list was going to be *way* longer when I started making it. Maybe meta isn't funny after all. I don't know though. I'm smiling right now, personally.

On the bright side, [our OS is not at war with anyone](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/13888/22949) and [someone is eager to help](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16313/22949).

---

Often, when someone comes to meta, they come here because they are concerned about something. Sometimes that doesn't leave too many opportunities for levity. Sometimes it does. Either way, that's okay. Being funny shouldn't get in the way of discussing our concerns, but taking ourselves too seriously shouldn't get in the way of it either.

By the way, you may have noticed [votes are used differently](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/16261/22949) on meta -- on the main site, they express evaluations of the *quality* of the post. On meta, they can serve that function, but at least as often are used to express *agreement* and *disagreement* with an opinion about site policy.

So if you do ever have something downvoted on meta, try not to take it too seriously. (Same deal for upvotes.) It's for a reason that votes on meta don't give or take away any reputation. Personally, I've sometimes entertained the notion that meta posts should have four vote buttons, and the total score should be represented as a [Gaussian integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), with quality on the real axis and agreement on the imaginary axis.

[image: Silly and not serious mock-up of agreement and quality evaluation axes for a voting voting on meta, exhibiting a severe lack of hand-drawn circles.]
<sup>To be viewed sideways from behind your screen. (Replace *i* with *j*, if using Python.)</sup>

But then I realize... that would just be silly.

Comment: +1 for "entertained the notion", quite an entertaining phrase amid an entertaining post.

Comment: i second the motion.

Comment: Possibly some posts need a scale, or a 'don't know, don't care...' button. As far as I remember with complex numbers `j` is used to not confused with `i` (as in current in electronics etc), didn't know Python could do 'em though :)

Comment: +i for 4 way voting

Answer (score 6):

As with the rest of the site - we want signal, not noise. Its fine to inject a *little* humour as part of *making a point*, but jokes posted as questions, questions posted as jokes, and things that are trying to be jokes or questions but arn't wouldn't belong here.

I use jokes as a tool, to help people remember, to make a point . I know my audience.

So, if you need to ask if we need humour, the answer is *no*. You'll know when to make funnies when you understand the site better.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Sir.  Have a good one

Answer (score 4):

You need a good sense of humour when you get down-voted :p

Comment: Right after you get down-vote/s :)
Thank you ive meet a human today.